# How to generate a random list of strings from an array

Tags: c#, .net, random

I want to generate a random list of 5 string values from an array of string.
 type options.  I have an `string[]` called 'Items':

```
private static string[] Items = new[]
{
    "Widgets", "Wotsits", "Grommits"
};
```

Using the options in this array, I want to instantiate a `List<string>` collection with 5 random strings.  I am trying to do it like this:

```
    public List<string> List()
    {
        var r = new Random();
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new List<string>()
        {
           Items[r.Next(Items.Length)]

        });
    }
```

I cannot get it to work. One problem I have is I use Enumerable.Range but this creates a type error which I have been unable to solve with .ToList().

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Right now you are creating a `List<List<string>>`. Are you trying to create a `List<string>`?

Comment: Can you explain in what way you "cannot get it to work"? What happens? Please detail any errors

Comment: `return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => Items[rng.Next(Items.Length)]).ToList();`

Comment: @Slai - not exactly a duplicate, here duplicate entries are needed (selecting 5 out of 3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `Select` statement you are creating a new list for each iteration, each list with one random element. Just remove the `new List<string>(){...}` part and simply write `Items[rng.Next(Items.Length)]`.
This way you will get a `List<string>` instead of a `List<List<string>>`.

Comment: Close, the `Select` will create an `IEnumerable<string>`, not a `List<string>`. Solution: add a `.ToList()`